# Inline nested jQuery template -- {{tmpl}}

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

In order to render a `<ul>` list with [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), I'd like to use [`{{tmpl}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl) sub-template tag, passing it an array of names to build my `<li>`s:

```
$.tmpl('<div>Hello <ul>{{tmpl(persons) "<li>${name}</li>"}}</ul></div>', {persons: [
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'Fred'}
]}).appendTo('body');
```

The problem is this http://jsfiddle.net/abernier/87dRV/ does not work :/

I don't really understand why since the documentation says

> template    The HTML markup or **text to use as a template**.

Any help appreciated :)

--

Obviously I can:

```
$.tmpl('<div>Hello <ul>{{each(i, name) persons}}<li>${name}</li>{{/each}}</ul></div>', {persons: [
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'Fred'}
]}).appendTo('body');
```

But I'd have prefered using `{{tmpl}}` here.

Answer (score 0):

I did not debug down yet to the point of seeing why your case is erroring out, but how about this as an alternative:

```
$.template("person", "<li>${name}</li>");
$.tmpl('<div>Hello <ul>{{tmpl(persons) "person" }}</ul></div>', {persons: [
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'Fred'}
]}).appendTo('body');
```

Alternative that uses an inline template:

```
$.tmpl('<div>Hello <ul>{{tmpl(persons) "<li>$' + '{name}</li>"}}</ul></div>', {persons: [
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'Fred'}
]}).appendTo('body');
```

The jQuery template plugin gets confused when it sees its own delimiters in it.  Just need to break it up into multiple strings.

Comment: Sure, but — as question's title indicates — I'd like to use here *inline* template, not pre-compiled one ;)

Comment: Hi RP Niemeyer, I've tried your last alternative, but didn't get it work: http://jsfiddle.net/abernier/Nr5C9/

Comment: I'm sorry, my second edit was done hastily, it should have looked like it does now.  The concatenation needs to happen inside the string.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Nr5C9/1/

Comment: Ok, now works! Well done, but that's weird, isn't it? Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: No, the jQuery Template plugin is looking for its own delimiters and happens to see one in the text that you are providing inside {{tmpl.   The parsing would have to get even more complex to properly handle a case like this. Not sure that I would say it is a bug, unless there was no workaround.

Comment: I've submitted an issue for this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/issues/132